# Seems like bug in Timestamp and Datetime diffs handing in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

If I run a query like following, to find difference in days for two points in time,

```sql
select 
    timestamp_diff(timestamp('2021-04-13T06:51:42'), timestamp('2021-04-05T06:56:24'), day)
   ,datetime_diff(timestamp('2021-04-13T06:51:42 UTC'), timestamp('2021-04-05T06:56:24 UTC'), day)
   ,timestamp_diff('2021-04-13T06:51:42', '2021-04-05T06:56:24', day)
   ,datetime_diff ('2021-04-13T06:51:42', '2021-04-05T06:56:24', day)
   ,datetime_diff (datetime('2021-04-13T06:51:42'), datetime('2021-04-05T06:56:24'), day)
```

I get following results:
`7 7 7 8 8`

[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be7fJ.png)

Time points are the same on all lines of query, it's exactly the same time frame, and I'd expect equal results.
Seems like temporal data diffs handling is not consistent, or I see expected behavior?

Comment: It's possible that timestamp_diff and datetime_diff do rounding different ways,
calculation of time differences between mentioned timestamps (in Excel) is 7,9967

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:-

A DATETIME object using a TIMESTAMP object supports an optional parameter to specify a timezone. If no timezone is specified, the default timezone, UTC, is used.

I executed your query by making some modifications as below and I get same results across.

[image]

```
 select 
    timestamp_diff(timestamp('2021-04-13T06:51:42' , "America/Los_Angeles"), timestamp('2021-04-05T06:56:24'), day)
   ,datetime_diff(timestamp('2021-04-13T06:51:42' , "America/Los_Angeles"), timestamp('2021-04-05T06:56:24 UTC'), day)
   ,timestamp_diff(timestamp('2021-04-13T06:51:42',"America/Los_Angeles"), '2021-04-05T06:56:24', day)
   ,datetime_diff ('2021-04-13T06:51:42', '2021-04-05T06:56:24', day)
   ,datetime_diff (datetime('2021-04-13T06:51:42'), datetime('2021-04-05T06:56:24'), day);
```

Follow this

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#datetime

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#time-zones

Comment: Both times intended to be in same timezone.
If we add missing timezones, we'll get differences back:

```
select 
    timestamp_diff(timestamp('2021-04-13T06:51:42'), timestamp('2021-04-05T06:56:24'), day)
   ,datetime_diff(timestamp('2021-04-13T06:51:42 UTC'), timestamp('2021-04-05T06:56:24 UTC'), day)
   ,timestamp_diff('2021-04-13T06:51:42', '2021-04-05T06:56:24', day)
   ,datetime_diff ('2021-04-13T06:51:42', '2021-04-05T06:56:24', day)
   ,datetime_diff (datetime('2021-04-13T06:51:42'), datetime('2021-04-05T06:56:24'), day)
```

```7 7 7 8 8```